# qooxdoo and openlayers. How to include OL libary files to qooxdoo compilation path?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, qooxdoo

I use qooxdoo together with OpenLayers. But I get this error when I try to compile the qooxdoo application:

```
- Warning: mobile02.page.Map (118): Unknown global symbol used: OpenLayers.Map
- Warning: mobile02.page.Map (119): Unknown global symbol used: OpenLayers.Layer.OSM
- Warning: mobile02.page.Map (150): Unknown global symbol used: OpenLayers.Projection
- Warning: mobile02.page.Map (152): Unknown global symbol used: OpenLayers.LonLat
- Warning: mobile02.page.Map (169): Unknown global symbol used: OpenLayers.Layer.Markers
- Warning: mobile02.page.Map (177): Unknown global symbol used: OpenLayers.Marker
- Warning: mobile02.page.Map (179): Unknown global symbol used: OpenLayers.Size
- Warning: mobile02.page.Map (180): Unknown global symbol used: OpenLayers.Pixel
- Warning: mobile02.page.Map (181): Unknown global symbol used: OpenLayers.Icon
```

At the same time, when I run the application, I get this error:

```
var map = new mobile02.page.Map();
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I wonder, how do I include the OpenLayers library into the qooxdoo project.

I looked here:
http://hg.ruilopes.com/openlayers-qooxdoo-hello

I also looked at the mobileshowcase provided with qooxdoo and I can't find the OpenLayers libary files anywhere. Can someone please tell me how this works? How do I include OpenLayers library to the qooxdoo compilation path?

Thanks for your time and kind concern.

Jenia

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original example for the OpenLayers usage.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/1d7e86b727289e97b55b6f6ebefe91b4655508bd/application/mobileshowcase/source/class/mobileshowcase/page/Maps.js

Take care of the ignore tag in line 23:

```
* @ignore(OpenLayers.*)
```

The OpenLayer example can be download directly from their server, like in the example.

You have to run ./generate.py source again after adding the class.